# java.lang.Object can not be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sametime

i am using eclipse 3.2 version.
in sametime based i am getting error on package: java.lang.Object can not be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

on build path JRE is JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6] (unbound)

when i set the JRE is JRE System Library [jclDesktop Win32 x86] then it give others errors like on function name of other classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a [lot of differences](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ledoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.rcp.jcl.desktop.javadoc/jclDesktop-J2SE50-Differences.html) between jclDesktop and Java 5. Which means, that Java code, written for Java 5 (or any other Sun/Oracle Java) will probably not compile with jclDesktop.

You can use jclDesktop as a JRE system library if you want to write applications for jclDesktop. If you have one Java application and want to *convert* it to jclDesktop, then you'll have to resolve all the compile time errors (and hope for the best).

Otherwise, install an Oracle Java SDK (JRE is enough although I'd recommend a JDK which comes with the `src.zip` file) and use that as JRE library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the .class file / bin folder from the project. Make a clean build after that and the error will go away.